# rails 3 : will paginate creating incorrect links

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

This is my route

```
match "/search/*keywords" => "public/search#index" ,:method=>:get,    :as=>:search_with_keywords
```

an example could be "/search/country-india/product_type-mobilephones"

am using will paginate to create pagination links
the */keywords is causing the following problem while creating the pagination link

```
<%= will_paginate @results, :container => false, :class => 'pagination ajax' %>
```

the generated link is "http://localhost:3000/search?keywords=country-india%2Fproduct_type-mobilephones&lang=en&page=2"

what i want is "http://localhost:3000/search/country-india/product_type-mobilephones?lang=en&page=2"

how can i achieve this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the Rails 3 version of Will Paginate (currently "3.0.pre2") then you can use the `:renderer` option and customize how the links are generated.

So first, if you're not up-to-date then you can follow the installation instructions and usage instructions from the [will paginate wiki](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki).

Then in `lib` you can create your own renderer that overwrites the link generation, perhaps something like

```
class SearchLinkRenderer < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer

  protected

  def url(page)

    @base_url_params ||= begin
      url_params = base_url_params
      merge_optional_params(url_params)
      url_params
    end

    url_params = @base_url_params.dup
    add_current_page_param(url_params, page)

    @template.search_with_keywords_url(url_params)
  end
end
```

and then call it with

```
<%= will_paginate @results, :container => false, :class => 'pagination ajax', :renderer => SearchLinkRenderer %>
```

The default renderer uses

```
@template.url_for(url_params)
```

which is what is "messing up" your links. You can use any path from `@template`, so

```
@template.search_with_keywords_url(url_params)
```

should do the trick. Now if you call will_paginate with your own renderer, it should pass use your path instead of `url_for`, and the parameters should match up nicely. If they don't then check what `url_params` is being set to and compare it with your route matchers.

There might be an easier way to overwrite this, but this seemed pretty straightforward and consistent with how will_paginate expects you to customize its output. I found that Rob Anderton has a great article on customizing will_paginate [here](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/8/3/roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate), so maybe they can offer more insight.

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in using [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) as an alternative to will_paginate for Rails 3. I discovered it via [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari) and was able to quickly and efficiently integrate it into my app. I also found my app's size decreased and performance increased noticeably after the switch.