# will_paginate gem generating wrong links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have 2 models Category and Course.

In my Course index page my url is like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/courses
```

And i can find courses by the categories, so at that time my url changes like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/courses/programming
```

where `programming` is a category.
So when i paginate the index page with respect to a category it generates a wrong url for next and previous urls:

```
/courses/show?id=programming&amp;page=2
```

I tried this answer but didn't any break through.
[rails 3 : will paginate creating incorrect links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258684/rails-3-will-paginate-creating-incorrect-links)
Can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: can we see the code you're using to generate the links?

Comment: `= will_paginate data, :class => "apple_pagination"`

Comment: routes.rb content please.